# Open readme.txt at end of installatin failed in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.6

We would like to open a notepad file at end of the installation. Hence I copied a readme.txt and placed under some local drive during installation then tried to open from that location. But, it is giving "The system cannot find the path specified" issue. However, it was working when I gave the local hard coded path as like "d:\readme.txt".

```
<Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
   <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='SimpleMvvmToolkit_2012'>          
   </Directory>
</Directory>


<Property Id='NOTEPAD'>Notepad.exe</Property>
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' Property='NOTEPAD' ExeCommand='[INSTALLDIR]Readme.txt'
              Return='asyncNoWait' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='LaunchFile' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Somewhere I did mistake but I couldn't find out exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a topic in the WiX SDK called [How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm) that could be used to launch the `readme.txt` if you just wanted to do that.

If you really don't want that user experience, I would recommend using the `WixShellExec` custom action to launch the `readme.txt` instead of trying to launch Notepad.exe. That way the `readme.txt` will open in the user's default .txt editor.  You can do that by:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#FileIdForReadMe.txt]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchFile" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA" 
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='LaunchFile' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Thanks rob. Your answers are very much helped me to progress my installer activities. I'm completed earlier with help of your guidance. The WiX is really a wonderful  and powerful tool to create installer. Great Work...!!

Comment: This launches the app before finish is clicked FYI.

Comment: Does this custom action perform any version checking? I tried this solution, but it only works if the installed file is the same file then in the msi - am i doing something wrong? Background: The exe to execute is a shared component, so the exe can be newer then the product to install.