# Running applications after installation in wix

Tags: c#, .net, wix, custom-action

This is my first project with WIX and installers. I want to run some vbscript and one application after installation is finished. The exe file is copied during the installation process but it's not the main program installed. All the scripts and application requires that they are run after all the files are copied. There is no custom GUI at this moment. My problem is if I put After = "InstallFinalize" int InstallExecuteSequence it always gives me error

Error   14  ICE77: LaunchNotePad is a in-script custom action.  It must be sequenced in between the InstallInitialize action and the InstallFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence table

In the example given I am trying to launch Notepad. Even if I try to run any other exe files a specific FileKey I get this error. It works only if I put Before = "InstallFinalize". More over it will work if I run the exe from ExeCommand, like the LaunchDeploymentManager custom action. What am I missing here

```
<Property Id='NOTEPAD'>Notepad.exe</Property>
<CustomAction Id='LaunchNotePad' Property='NOTEPAD' Execute='commit' ExeCommand='' Impersonate='no' Return='asyncNoWait'/>

<!--<CustomAction Id="LaunchDeployementManager" Directory="SERVICEFOLDER" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start DeploymentManager.exe" />-->

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchNotePad" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <!--<Custom Action="LaunchDeployementManager" After="InstallFinalize" />-->
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: I think Rob's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205360/open-readme-txt-at-end-of-installatin-failed-in-wix might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have found that Execute = 'commmit' and After = "InstallFinalize" does not work together. If I remove Execute='commit' from the custom action it works. But why is this?

Comment: Not to comment with another link, but to comment with another link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631519/windows-installer-custom-actions-commit-action-wont-get-executed I don't believe commit is execution type you want in this case.

Comment: This EXE, does it change the configuration of the machine or is it merely  show a read me, launch my app type exe?

Comment: The exe actually creates some Dbs, change some configurations etc.